Running Windows and Linux containers on docker and WSL
For a project we're working on, we have a very specific requirement: we need to run both Windows Containers and Linux Containers over Docker. On a Windows machine running Windows 11 and the latest version of WSL (2.2.4.0), we followed this guide to set up Docker on Windows for Windows Containers, and installed docker-ce on WSL to run the Linux Containers.
We also configured WSL networking mode as mirrored and turned on the hostAddressLoopback experimental feature, as per Microsoft’s instructions here.
Using the newly created Docker context, we can launch Linux Containers on WSL and access them from the host OS. Similarly, we can launch Windows Containers and communicate with them on the host OS.
We have a particular requirement where the containers on WSL need to communicate with the containers on the host OS, and this is where we run into a problem.
We can't connect to the Windows container from within WSL, no matter which address we use. We tried localhost, the IP of the Windows container, all addresses returned by the ip a command, and more, but all attempts resulted in timeouts. However, if we run a Python echo server on Windows (non-containerised) and bind a port (e.g., port 8080), we can use telnet from WSL to connect to it without any issues.
Given that services running directly on Windows (non-containesized) can be accessed from WSL, we are wondering if there is some port forwarding we're missing that would allow the Windows Containers and Linux Containers to communicate. Or, alternatively, we might need to create a specific network with a predefined subnet to put both containers in.
We tried all of the above experiments with Windows Firewall both enabled and disabled, but the issue persists.
Any ideas?

Is there a requirement that you cannot use Docker Desktop? If I understand what you're asking here, it's a lot easier to diagnose and troubleshoot WSL2 networking issues with something visual like Docker Desktop. Oh, also, I assume you've tried:
Set-NetFirewallHyperVVMSetting -Name '{40E0AC32-46A5-438A-A0B2-2B479E8F2E90}' -DefaultInboundAction Allow or New-NetFirewallHyperVRule -Name "MyWebServer" -DisplayName "My Web Server" -Direction Inbound -VMCreatorId '{40E0AC32-46A5-438A-A0B2-2B479E8F2E90}' -Protocol TCP -LocalPorts 80

I have probably missed that from the initial post - Im using docker desktop on windows. I did try those settings and also turning the firewall completely. Still doesn't work.
